# @{\hskip} and \multicolumns

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Consider the following table

```
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \toprule
    N   &       \multicolumn3c{L-family}    &   \multicolumn2c{H-family}    \\
    n   &   large   &   Large   &   LARGE   &       huge    &   Huge        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

I want to emphasis the grouping of columns, hence the @-construction

```
\def\htc#1{ {\hskip#1\tabcolsep} }
\begin{tabular}{c  @\htc4  ccc  @\htc4  cc}
    \toprule
    N   &       \multicolumn3c{L-family}    &   \multicolumn2c{H-family}    \\
    n   &   large   &   Large   &   LARGE   &       huge    &   Huge        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Now I have to fine-tune the multicolumn because the horizontal space is off

```
\begin{tabular}{c  @\htc4  ccc  @\htc4  cc}
\toprule
N   &   \multicolumn3{@\htc{-3}c}{L-family} &   \multicolumn2{@\htc0c}{H-family}
\\
n   &   large   &   Large   &   LARGE       &       huge        &       Huge    
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Why the dirty constants?
Can it be done in a more automatic way?

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\parskip1em

Consider the following table

\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \toprule
    N   &       \multicolumn3c{L-family}    &   \multicolumn2c{H-family}    \\
    n   &   large   &   Large   &   LARGE   &       huge    &   Huge        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

~

I want to emphasis the grouping of columns, hence the @-construction

\def\htc#1{ {\hskip#1\tabcolsep} }
\begin{tabular}{c  @\htc4  ccc  @\htc4  cc}
    \toprule
    N   &       \multicolumn3c{L-family}    &   \multicolumn2c{H-family}    \\
    n   &   large   &   Large   &   LARGE   &       huge    &   Huge        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

~

Now I have to fine-tune the multicolumn

\begin{tabular}{c  @\htc4  ccc  @\htc4  cc}
\toprule
N   &   \multicolumn3{@\htc{-3}c}{L-family} &   \multicolumn2{@\htc0c}{H-family}
\\
n   &   large   &   Large   &   LARGE       &       huge        &       Huge    
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

Why the dirty constantss?

\end{document}
```

PS
In this question:
[Issue with alignment when using multi-column and @{\hskip}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519680/),
The answer suggests to suppress `\tabcolsep` using an empty `@{}`.
One can see that this does not always give you the desired result.

Comment: Not bracing `\multicolumn3c` looks very weird but not bracing the `@` expression looks positively dangerous. If you use the `array` package (which should almost always be used for tables) it does give the expected error.   In the non array case you are relying on premature expansion of `\htc` to add the brace arguments for `@`  which sort of works by accident..

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. `\htc` is the simplification I made for this post; in my document they are written in full. On the other hand, `\multicolumn3c` is intentional as they are rarely more than two tokens.

Comment: but being single token here is the cause of the problem. I know it works but it looks so weird, and it will bite you.

Comment: Seeing your answer, I now can feel the bite =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` expressions are part of the right hand edge of the relevant column, so when using `\multicolumn` repeat the full component for the span including its right hand `@` expression:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\def\htc#1{ {\hskip#1\tabcolsep} }
\begin{document}

\parskip1em


I want to emphasis the grouping of columns, hence the @-construction


\begin{tabular}{c  @{\htc4}  ccc  @{\htc4}  cc}
    \toprule
    N   &       \multicolumn{3}{c@{\htc4}}{L-family}    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{H-family}    \\
    n   &   large   &   Large   &   LARGE   &       huge    &   Huge        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. So the key is the concept that `c@{}` is the correct grouping. Learn something everyday. Thank you so much. Didn't expect it to be so easy

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its built-in command `\Block`, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\htc}{m}{\hspace{#1\tabcolsep}}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c@{\htc{4}}ccc@{\htc{4}}cc}
\toprule
N & \Block{1-3}{L-family}       &&& \Block{1-2}{H-family} \\
n & large &   Large   & LARGE     &  huge    &   Huge     \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Antiintuitive that it needs several compilation (because the original problem is at most a linear equation). That being said, thank you for suggesting new packages.